# How to check if only one variable of three is set

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I would like to restrict the user to inputting (through `Getopt::Long`) only one value out of a possible three. The values are 'pc-number', 'ip-address', and 'surname'.

When there were two values, I was doing the following:

```
if ((!$pc_number and !$address) or ($pc_number and $address)) {
    pod2usage("You must supply pc_number OR ip_address.");
    exit;
} elsif ($pc_number) {
    (do stuff)
}
```

How can I simply make sure only one out of three variables are set by the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the number of true values using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).  Could also check for [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) if that was appropriate:

```
if ( 1 != grep {$_} ( $pc_number, $address, $surname ) ) {
    pod2usage "You must supply one and only one parameter: pc_number, ip_address, surname.";
    exit;

} elsif ($pc_number) {
    ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it:

```
if (($x xor $y xor $z) and not $x && $y && $z) {
    ... # one (and only one) is true
}
```

...although I'm not sure it's the kind of thing you'd want to encounter in code you have to maintain.

Comment: This is a good solution. I agree it's a little convoluted, but a comment makes the intent pretty obvious. Thank you very much.

Comment: This does work in this specific case, but it's not expandable.  Meaning, if there were 4 values, this style would return true if 3 of them were true.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote this.